# linq orderby query inside of an if statement

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to do some code which basically says do search, if orderByLastName is true order by lastname and if false order by first name.

```
if(orderByLastName)
{
    var query = from p in db.People
                orderby p.LastName
                select new {Name = p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName}
}
else
{
     var query = from p in db.People
                orderby p.FirstName
                select new {Name = p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName}
}
```

The above code is my attempt at accomplishing this.  It doesn't work because query does not exist outside of the if context which is clearly bad!  And also I'm pretty sure the code violates the dry principle.  Can someone see a nicer way of doing this?  Thanks.

Comment: I noticed that you actually order by FirstName when orderByLastName is true... is this by design?

Comment: No, just a mistake!  Have changed it now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run as many queries on your IQueryable collection as you want, all of them will be executed right in place where you will make first cast of conversion to IEnumerable.

```
var query = db.People;    
if(orderByLastName)
{
     query  = query.OrderBy(t=>t.LastName)
}
else
{
     query  = query.OrderBy(t=>t.FirstName)
}
var result = query.Select(t=> new {Name = t.FirstName + " " + t.LastName});
```

Comment: I can't get this to work.  When I get to line 4 intellisense only gives t.Name as an option and not t.LastName.

Comment: Thanks.  I can only get mine to work if I on the last line I change it to var query2 = query.Select(t=> new {Name = t.FirstName + " " + t.LastName});

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution :

```
Func<PeopleType, string> orderby;

if(orderByLastName)
        orderby = t => t.LastName;
else
        orderby = t => t.FirstName;

var result = db.People.OrderBy(orderby).Select(t => new { Name = t.FirstName + " " + t.LastName });
```